# laravel 4 listen for event when pivot table entry deleted or detached

Tags: php, events, laravel

I'm trying to carry out some actions when an entry in an intermediate/pivot table is deleted.

I've tried creating a model for the intermediate table but this does not fire - so I assume the model is not touched when the detach event from the parent model is used to delete the entry.

**Updated:**
I want to listen for the delete event when using the `sync()` method. At that point I'm not aware of which records are being deleted.

Here's what I've tried:

**In MyintermediateModel.php:**

```
public function delete()
{
// do something
}
```

This doesn't fire

**in global.php**

```
Event::listen('eloquent.deleting: Reservation_resource',     function($reservation_resource) {
//    do something
}
```

this doesn't fire

So - is there an event (or something similar) I can attach to that will fire when a pivot table entry is being deleted?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can always fire the event yourself.

```
public function delete()
{
    Event::fire('reservation_resources.deleting', $reservation_resource); // If you want to fire before deleting
    // delete record
    Event::fire('reservation_resources.deleted', $reservation_resource); // If you want to fire after deleting
}
```

Then just listen for the event you fired

```
Event::listen('reservation_resource.deleted', function($reservation_resource)
{
    //do something
});
```

Comment: I'm using the 'sync' method with an update so I'm not able to know which records are being deleted. I thought I could listen for the event to do some tidying up actions and logs.